# Does backbone.js router support normal urls?

Tags: backbone.js

Normal urls like

```
www.example.com/posts/1

www.example.com/about
```

Cause the documentation and blog posts about it are only with urls like:

```
www.example.com/#/posts/1

www.example.com/#/about
```

this is my code:

```
var Workspace = Backbone.Router.extend({

    routes: {
        "/posts/new":                 "postsNew",
    },

    postsNew: function() {
        console.log("HELLO");
    }

});


jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    var w = new Workspace;
    Backbone.history.start();

});
```

But nothing happens on /posts/new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
Backbone.history.start();
```

To

```
Backbone.history.start({pushState: true})
```

This setting enables Backbone to use the HTML5 History API. Which, handles cleaning the url and updating the browser history.

It's not enabled by default because some older browsers still lack support for HTML5.